# Jenkins / when{ changelog '*****' } phrase, any equivalent in scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've designed a Declarative Pipeline for my CI job, including some conditional stages related to branch changelog magic words. It's working fine, though trying to establish a flow control in Declarative Pipeline results in a lot of stages which are redundant in some ways.

Due to that, I've decided to try Scripted Pipeline syntax, however I couldn't find any equivalent of "changelog" symbol, which is useful for determining a magic word match in branch changelog.

I was expecting I can move on like this:

```
//Declarative
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Dummy') {
            when
            {
                changelog '\\[ci BUILD\\]'
            }

            steps
            {
                echo 'Building dummy...'
            }
        }
    }
}

//Scripted
node {
    stage('Dummy') {
        if (changelog '\\[ci BUILD\\]')
        {
            echo 'Building dummy...'
        }
    }
}
```

However it did not work. Is there any way to set up this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to write a Groovy function using regex find operator, tested on Jenkins 2.375.2 with "Pipeline: Supporting APIs" plugin, version 839.v35e2736cfd5c, and it's working correctly. Here is the implementation:

```
boolean matchChangelog(GString ptrnString)
{
    def ptrn = ~"${ptrnString}"

    for(i in currentBuild.changeSets)
    {
        for(j in i.items)
        {
            if(j.msg =~ ptrn)
            {
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

With using this method, This:

```
    when{ expression{ return matchChangelog("pattern") }
```

is equivalent of this:

```
    when{ changelog 'pattern' }
```